# Fastapi + Strawberry GraphQL

Tags: python, graphql, fastapi, strawberry-graphql

I'm currently building a microservice with `fastapi`.

I want to expose my underlying data via `graphql` on an additional route.
Direct integration from starlette has been deprecated so I tried to use one of the recommended packages `strawberry`.
At the moment, it seems impossible to use in combination with grapqhl.

### Example

`my_grapqhql.py`

```
from typing import List
import strawberry

@strawberry.type
class Book:
    title: str
    author: str

@strawberry.type
class Query:
    books: List[Book]

schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query)
```

### What I tried

In the fastapi documentation, asgi components are added like so:

`main.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from strawberry.asgi import GraphQL
from .my_graphql.py import schema

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(GraphQL, schema=schema)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'app'`

when I switch the last line to mount a module is atleast starts:

```
app.mount("/graphql", GraphQL(schema))
```

but the route doesn't load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been documented here: https://strawberry.rocks/docs/integrations/fastapi#fastapi

From the docs

```py
import strawberry

from fastapi import FastAPI
from strawberry.fastapi import GraphQLRouter


@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field
    def hello(self) -> str:
        return "Hello World"


schema = strawberry.Schema(Query)


graphql_app = GraphQLRouter(schema)


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(graphql_app, prefix="/graphql")
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'strawberry.fastapi'; 'strawberry' is not a package

Comment: @KansaiRobot do you have reproduction for this? did you install `strawberry` or `strawberry-graphql`? (it should be the latter)

Comment: I used `pip install 'strawberry-graphql[fastapi]'`

Comment: Call with ` uvicorn strawberry2:app --reload` . Then the error appears. `strawberry2.py` being the file name

Comment: do you also have a file called strawberry?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Testing the FatAPI implementation from documentation on a fresh conda evnironment where I just installed `strawberry-graphql[fastapi]` and `uvicorn`. I am unable to launch the server, always ending up with `No module named 'strawberry'`

Answer (score 0):

The new way of adding Strawberry with FastApi which is in documentation also

```py
app = FastAPI()
schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query,mutation=Mutation,config=StrawberryConfig(auto_camel_case=True))
graphql_app = GraphQLRouter(schema)
app.include_router(graphql_app, prefix="/graphql")
```